# Ubuntu 17.10 too slow on boot

Tags: boot, grub2, mount, fstab

Hi I have problem from the day I updated to ubuntu 17.10 the boot time has been significantly high. I have done some research but I don't know what might be problem and where to change.So far I found this

- Run command **sudo blkid** and see the output
- Check inside the **/etc/fstab** and compare the output and change it

Here's what I have from the command

> sudo blkid

Outputs:

```
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop1: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop2: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop3: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop4: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop5: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop6: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop7: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/sda1: UUID="6C0C-74A5" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI System Partition" PARTUUID="4636d28d-02ac-4a03-abdc-76cefb7491ee"
/dev/sda2: UUID="4917e948-ef3c-42c9-abe2-3ed0b0e9eb29" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="749546bb-4f38-4670-99b2-d4def6f6e9e3"
/dev/loop8: TYPE="squashfs"
```

Whereas my

> gedit fstab

shows this

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=4917e948-ef3c-42c9-abe2-3ed0b0e9eb29 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
#UUID=6C0C-74A5  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
UUID=6C0C-74A5  /boot/efi   vfat    defaults    0   1
```

What is wrong here and where do I need to change to make the boot time fast?

And here's the result from

> systemd-analyze blame

Outputs

```
43.523s plymouth-quit-wait.service
33.944s mysql.service
23.355s snapd.service
16.149s wicd.service
13.803s dev-sda2.device
11.805s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
11.743s php7.0-fpm.service
10.097s networking.service
9.256s postfix@-.service
8.969s keyboard-setup.service
8.104s NetworkManager.service
8.045s apache2.service
7.958s gdm.service
7.451s teamviewerd.service
7.163s apparmor.service
6.723s ModemManager.service
5.695s udisks2.service
5.543s plymouth-read-write.service
5.057s fwupd.service
4.612s gpu-manager.service
4.610s rsyslog.service
4.547s accounts-daemon.service
3.689s dev-loop8.device
```

Comment: mysql, apache, postfix and php is usually not used on desktop installs. Find out why you need them, uninstall if necessary.

Comment: It is necessary for me to have mysql ,apache and php.

Comment: Cool, I'd edit the post and mention this, also look into `systemd-analyze plot`, it would create a nice svg. use this for an example; `systemd-analyze plot > bootup-01.svg`

Comment: So should I add svg??I have already got it in png format

Comment: add svg??? I'd prefer svg as it is a vector graphics format and you can zoom in as much as you need. And yeah, sharing it would probably help.